# Prevent Templates From Discarding DOM Elements

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I am attempting to integrate a `D3.js` visualization into a Meteor app. After the page has loaded, a D3 function injects DOM elements into a `<div>` in my template, based on available data.

Whenever there is a reactive update anywhere on the page, however, Meteor dumps the contents of the template that were injected by my D3.js function. I can re-insert the elements, but this leads to an undesirable flicker and decrease in performance.

Any idea on how to suppress this dropping of externally injected elements? I gather that since these elements were not part of the template originally, they are discarded as part of Meteor's 'cleanup' process.

Comment: We need to add a good way to preserve programmatically embedded elements.  The problem is that when a template is re-rendered it replaces whatever is in the DOM with whatever it rendered to -- it doesn't know what elements were added by other means.

Comment: @dgreensp - that's a feature, not a flaw.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the introduction of the Spark templating engine in version 0.4.0, they've introduced the {{#constant}} block helpers to address this issue.

http://meteor.com/blog/2012/08/31/introducing-spark-a-new-live-page-update-engine

Your html template should look something like this....

```
<template name="samplePageTemplate">
    <div id="samplePage" class="page">
        {{#constant}}
        <div id="sampleGraph"></div>
        {{/constant}}
    </div>
</template>
```

And the javascript should look something like this...

```
Template.samplePageTemplate.destroyed = function () {
    this.handle && this.handle.stop();
};
Template.samplePageTemplate.rendered = function () {
    self.node = self.find("svg");
    if (!self.handle) {
        self.handle = Meteor.autorun(function(){

            $('#sampleGraph').html('');
            renderChart();

        });
    };
};

function renderChart(){

    // lots of d3 chart specific stuff 

    var vis = d3.select("#sampleGraph").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
        .attr("height", window.innerHeight)
        .append("svg:g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

    // more d3 chart specific stuff

    });
};
```

I've sometimes had to use self.node instead of self.handle, but otherwise it should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving unique ids to the D3 injected elements (or at least a parent element)? From the doc (http://docs.meteor.com/#livehtml):

> Just make sure that each of your focusable elements either has a unique id, or has a name that is unique within the closest parent that has an id. Meteor will preserve these elements even when their enclosing template is rerendered, but will still update their children and copy over any attribute changes.

Comment: I agree that the documentation seems to imply that having a unique ID attached to an element would prevent it from being dropped, but this does not seem to be the case. In my application, each element inserted had a unique ID, but they were removed on a reactive update nevertheless.